# Express - Serve specific static apps depending on the sub domain

Tags: node.js, express

i want to serve different static content depending on the subdomain

> app1.example.com
>   app2.example.com
>   app3.example.com

```
const app1path = path.join(__dirname, "public", "app1");

this.app.use(vhost("app1.localhost:1234", serveStatic(app1path)));
```

however i just get `Cannot GET /`. What am i doing wrong here?

**server.js**

```
import App from "./app";

class Server {

    constructor() {

        this.app = new App();
        this.instance = this.app.instance;
        this.config = this.app.config;
        this.server = this.instance.listen(this.config.port, "0.0.0.0");
        console.log("Server Running On: 0.0.0.0:" + this.config.port);

    }

}
export default Server;
```

**app.js**

```
import express from "express";
import Config from "./config";
import Router from "./routes";
import cors from "cors";
import morgan from "morgan";

class App {

    constructor() {

        // Init
        this.instance = express();
        this.config = new Config();

        // Middleware
        this.instance.use(morgan("combined"));
        this.instance.use(cors());
        this.instance.use(express.json());
        this.instance.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

        // Routes
        this.router = new Router(this.instance);
    }

}

export default App;
```

**routes.js**

```
    import Config from "./config";
    import CoreRouter from "./app/core.router";
    import vhost from "vhost";
    import serveStatic from "serve-static";
    import path from "path";

    class Router {

        constructor(app) {

            this.app = app;
            this.config = new Config();

            this.app.use("/api/v1/core", CoreRouter);

            const app1 = path.join(__dirname, "public", "app1");

            this.app.use(vhost("app1.localhost", serveStatic(app1)));

        }
    }


export default Router;
```

**/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.0.1   app1.localhost
```

UPDATE: Ive provided some more code to hopefully help me with debugging this problem. navigating to `app1.localhost:1234` in the browser returns me with `Cannot GET /`

Comment: Have you added `app1.localhost` to your hosts file? If not, what Operating System are you running?

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech yes i have added it to /etc/hosts

Comment: Looking through examples online, I don't think you should include the port in your vhost function. Try `vhost("app1.localhost",...`.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech good point i removed the port but unfortunately it did not solve the problem.